# Cannot execute Java Classes on OSX

Tags: java, macos, shell, terminal

I'm trying to execute a java build using commandline in OSX 10.10,

The command I'm using:

```
java -classpath ./bin;./libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar example.hello.Server localhost:80
```

I've got MAMP up and running on the classPath and java is in the same "classes" directory.
Terminal is showing all options that can be used with java and is not executing the file. The same happends when using -cp.

Thanks

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting the default help document; https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b7d07081731de79db07a

Comment: I don't think MAMP likely has anything to do with this, unless you need it just to provide the database for your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a misplaced `;` instead of `:` in your classpath string. Try:

```
java -classpath ./bin:./libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar example.hello.Server localhost:80
```

Remember on OSX (or any other Unix flavor system) path separator is `:` not `;` as on `Windows/DOS`

Comment: Thanks it worked. Code was used by a teacher's DOS example. So didn't see the ;.